# Are we playing the Victorious virtue correctly?

Tags: 7th-sea-2e

The Victorious virtue reads as follows:

> Activate your virtue the first time you Wound a Villain during a fight to make her take a Dramatic Wound in addition to the Wounds you normally deal.

Our understanding is that if you hit a Strength 5 villain with a single raise, the outcome is this:

Before:

o o o o o O o o o o o O o o o o o O o o o o o O

After:

x o o o o X o o o o o O o o o o o O o o o o o O

After an additional hit for three wounds:

x x x x o X o o o o o O o o o o o O o o o o o O

But since you have to activate it the first time you hit the villain, and since villains don't get wound penalties, this seems like it ultimately only adds a single extra wound (unless you do some serious dramatic wound stacking shenanigans).

**Is this correct? Or am I missing something that makes the extra dramatic wound important?**

Pre-suppositions:

- Villains do not take wound penalties ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/7thSea/comments/5dc7lu/dramatic_wounds/))
- Villain wounds work like hero wounds, except that they have a different number of flesh wounds at each tier ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/7thSea/comments/6lfnl7/rules_clarification_do_villain_wounds_work/djw0apc/)).
- "Taking a dramatic wound" means bubbling in the next available dramatic wound on the death spiral, without bubbling in the intervening flesh wound ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/7thSea/comments/6nh8gh/what_does_victorious_do/?ref=share&ref_source=link)).
- I know that it stacks with firearms, but as my group is five players they can go down the "everyone shoots the villain and he dies" route without using this virtue. I'd rather they didn't.

---

> Dramatic wounds do not heal naturally, only when narratively appropriate. So if one of the parties escape, the next time they battle, those wounds are still there.

Dramatic wounds heal at the end of each episode (page 181). I usually run about one episode / session, so each villain should have no more than one dramatic wound per Victorious player.

Still, even if they encounter the villain a second time, the benefit seems low. A strength 5 villain takes 24 wounds to incapacitate. A strength five villain with a dramatic wound from his last appearance takes 23 wounds to incapacitate.

> When you take enough dramatic wounds, you are defeated, regardless of your actual wounds.
>
> That said, those extra dramatic wounds will help you bringing down villains sooner than you normally would.

Using a strength five villain as an example again, he takes 24 wounds to beat against a non-victorious party. He takes 23 wounds to kill against a party with victorious. That's not much faster.

If the victorious player could time their virtue perfectly (activating it when they deal the 18th wound), you could defeat the villain in 18 wounds instead of 24... But the virtue requires you to activate it "the first time you hit a villain."

You can drop the villain in record time if you invest heavily in dramatic wounds (e.g. four heroes with Victorious, or some number with firearms)... But the system looks broken at that point because you're guaranteed to defeat any villain in a single round of combat.

I'd rather not tell my players "this virtue is good if you optimize to the point that the system breaks" :)

Comment: I removed my answer, as [Michael Curry](https://www.reddit.com/r/7thSea/comments/6lfnl7/rules_clarification_do_villain_wounds_work/djw0apc/) pretty much said that Victorious shouldn't be used as written, or doesn't know how it exactly works.

Comment: Ditto with ShadowKras - it looks like (based on your second link) that you are either using it correctly or it is poorly described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, you are correct

According to [Michael Curry (designer)](https://www.reddit.com/r/7thSea/comments/6lfnl7/rules_clarification_do_villain_wounds_work/djw0apc/), you track villain's dramatic wounds exactly like hero's dramatic wounds:

> Dramatic Wounds are tracked the same for Heroes as they are for Villains.
>
> "Doesn't this mean that automatic Dramatic Wounds are less valuable for Heroes to inflict?" Maybe, yeah, unless you plan them out smartly. Save your auto-DW to knock a Villain to their 4th Wound, or to make them question whether or not they want to keep tangling with you. After all, a Villain (in-world) doesn't necessarily know that they have another X Wounds before they go Helpless. What they know is "I JUST GOT SHOT AND IT HURTS A LOT AND THERE'S A BUNCH OF BLOOD AND I DON'T THINK I WANT TO DIE HERE."

This introduces a few weird situations with *Victorious*, where we are granting villains extra health by skipping dramatic wounds once they have taken a hit from *Victorious*. Which directly diminishes the value of *Victorious* for heroes (unless pvping is happening).

### House Rule: Track Dramatic Wounds independently

If we check the book (page 194), we see that you don't skip wounds already taken.

> **Once a Villain has Wounds equal to her Strength, the next single Wound she takes becomes a Dramatic Wound**. So a Strength 10 Villain can take 10 Wounds, but her 11th Wound is a Dramatic Wound.When a Villain takes 4 Dramatic Wounds, she is defeated and (like a Hero) becomes Helpless. A Strength 10 Villain becomes Helpless upon taking the 44th Wound in a Scene

The bolded part is how villains take additional dramatic wounds, so each time they take *strenght+1* in damage, they gain a new dramatic wound, regardless of how many wounds they had before. If it was me, I would either mark the last available dramatic wound instead of the first or note those wounds separately from those gained from regular wounds.

Most likely, I would track villain wounds and dramatic wounds independently. If a hero does 1 wound and one dramatic wound to a strength 5 villain, they will still have one wound towards their *next* dramatic wound.

> Using a strength five villain as an example again, he takes 24 wounds to beat against a non-victorious party. He takes 23 wounds to kill against a party with victorious. That's not much faster.

So, if they already have a dramatic wound, you now must cause 5 fewer wounds to bring him down. As he started combat with an additional dramatic wound. If you skip a dramatic wound, he effectively had to take 11 wounds to take the second dramatic wound instead of 6 wounds. If two players had Victorious, the first dramatic wounds from wounds would only happen after 16 wounds, which sounds like the Virtue is buffing your villains instead of helping players to bring them down.

Converting this to a visual chart:

- Without Victorious

  oooooXoooooXoooooXoooooX
- With Victorious

  XoooooXoooooXoooooX

Once four Xs are marked, he would be defeated.

In addition, although you do not gain bonus dice against villains with dramatic wounds, there are two effects that still apply:

- Dramatic wounds **do not heal naturally**, only when narratively appropriate or at the end of an Episode. So if one of the parties escape, the next time they battle, those wounds are still there.
- When you take enough dramatic wounds (normally four), you are **defeated**, regardless of your actual wounds.

That said, those extra dramatic wounds will help you bring down villains sooner than you normally would.

Comment: I'm only familiar with *1e*, so I don't know if the idea that *My group is five players so they can go down the everyone-shoots-the-villain-and-he-dies route without using this virtue* also needs clarifying or not. Can heroes actually *kill* villains without the villains' consent in *2e*?

Comment: Defeat or death of villains is on the gm hands. I have to check my book again to confirm this. But im sure that taking 4 wounds (normally) means defeat.

Comment: I've added some sections dealing with these points to my question. But I guess these are the important questions I have for you: Do your players take Victorious frequently? Are they as excited/happy to activate Victorious as they are to activate their other virtues?

Comment: Regarding that table; should it or shouldn't it reflect the regular wound also struck on the Villain? If so, it'd start "XxooooX..."

Comment: Your edit is very interesting. If I understand you right, you're thinking villain wounds don't use the "filling in bubbles" mechanic that players use, and instead use two independent counters: flesh wounds, and dramatic wounds.

Comment: To be honest i wouldnt even use a chart or life spiral, but write down *thresholds* for each dramatic wound. Like this: wounds 24 (6, 12, 18, 24)

Comment: @AceCalhoon you could use the bubble method, but when victorious triggers, i would fill the dramatic wounds from right to left. That way, the mechanics for wounds remain the same and the virtue does what the book says it does, as the effect is *in addition to the wounds you normally deal*.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely wouldn't use physical bubbles for this. I was more looking at the distinction "against heroes this virtue fills in the left-most dramatic wound, but against villains it effectively fills in the right-most one." That's a bit odd, but your rules quote is reasonable, and it would make the virtue a lot more useful for players.

Comment: Michael Curry (one of the devs) has confirmed that this reading is [not the way the rules are intended to work](https://www.reddit.com/r/7thSea/comments/6lfnl7/rules_clarification_do_villain_wounds_work/djw0apc/). Could you reframe this answer in terms of a house rule?

Comment: @AceCalhoon let me know when he answers your question. He might be thinking about another context and not considering how Victorious work.

Comment: Updating the answer so this isn't left unanswered.